# How do I compile a C function with multiple dependencies and call it from R?

Tags: r, c, build

I have a function written in C that I want to compile and call from R.  It lives in `ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2.c` which depends on these additional files:

```
CompactClassificationTree.c
CompactEnsemble.c
ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2_data.c
ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2_initialize.c
ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2_terminate.c
findNode.c
predictOneWithCache.c
rt_nonfinite.c
rtGetInf.c
rtGetNaN.c
updateCache.c
```

How do I compile this code then call the function (declared as below) in an R process?

```c
double ensembleBaggedTreesExtendedStay_V2(
    double TransferredYesNo,
    double BleedDisYesNo,
    double PreOpAlbumin,
    double PreOpHCT,
    double ASAClass,
    double ComplexYesNo);
```

I tried creating a shared library linking all of the object files, but I could not call the function from R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example for a file `a.c` with dependency `b.c`.  Of course, depending on your use case, you can consider just writing an R package containing the C source files, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

```c
/* a.c */

#include <Rinternals.h>

double add2(double, double);

SEXP R_add2(SEXP x, SEXP y) {
    if (LENGTH(x) == 0 || LENGTH(y) == 0)
        error("oops");
    double *px = REAL(x), *py = REAL(y);
    return ScalarReal(add2(px[0], py[0]));
}
```

```c
/* b.c */

double add2(double x, double y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Then, in an R process:

```r
## R CMD COMPILE a.c b.c
tools::Rcmd(c("COMPILE", "a.c", "b.c"))
```

```
clang -I"/usr/local/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -flto=thin -c a.c -o a.o
clang -I"/usr/local/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -flto=thin -c b.c -o b.o
```

```r
## R CMD SHLIB -o ab.so a.o b.o
tools::Rcmd(c("SHLIB", "-o", "ab.so", "a.o", "b.o"))
```

```
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -Wall -g -O2 -pedantic -mmacosx-version-min=13.0 -arch arm64 -falign-functions=64 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -flto=thin -fPIC -Wl,-mllvm,-threads=4 -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o ab.so a.o b.o -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

```r
dyn.load("ab.so")
.Call("R_add2", 1, 2)
```

```
[1] 3
```